# 12.10 login error "Unable to mount Floppy Disk"

Tags: 12.10, disk, floppy

After a fresh install of 12.10 on a system with 6 users.  Every user that logs in gets the message

> Error mounting system-managed device /dev/fd0: Command-line `mount
>   "/media/floppy0"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/fd0
>   is not a valid block device

No on wants to mount a floppy and the drive is empty.  This happens on every single login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/+bug/1054414) open about this issue.
As a workoraund...you can try to disable the floppy drive in your BIOS's machine.
***(If nobody uses floppy drive)***.

Best Regards.

Comment: Interesting find, I hadn't see that one.  This could very well stem from the same source but let me point out the differences in case someone else comes along.  This one references non-existent floppy drives and an icon that can't be unlocked from the launcher.  I actually have a drive and I was able to remove the icon from the launcher.  I will watch that bug though, thanks.